# Data structure for querying maximum of a rolling total

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, arrays

Let $A = \{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$ be a set of numbers and $w$ be some number. Define $p_w^{A}: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ as $$p_w^{A}(r) = |\{i \in \{1, \ldots, n\} | r \leq a_i \leq r + w\}|.$$ Note that $p_w^{A}(\mathbb{R})$, the image of the whole $\mathbb{R}$ under $p_w^A$, is finite. Define $MRT_w(A) = \max p_w^{A}(\mathbb{R})$.

Let's fix a number $w$. The task is to implement a data structure which can store a set of values and has the following interface:

- Add value.
- Remove value.
- Compute $MRT_w(A)$, where $A$ is the set of all values which are currently stored in a data structure.

Can you get an $O(\log n)$ complexity for all 3 operations?

Comment: @D.W. There is no source for this problem. I came up with this problem while I was thinking about [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/160012/find-a-unit-square-containing-most-of-the-points) question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a data structure (call it $D$), which can store pairs of $(key, value)$ (where $key$ and $value$ are some numbers) and has the following interface:

1. Put $(key, value)$ pair to a data structure (if such key is already in a data structure then ignore this operation). We will refer to this operation as $D.put(key, value)$.
2. Remove $key$ from a data structure. Denotation: $D.remove(key)$.
3. Given a pair of numbers $(l, r)$ and number $v$, consider all keys, which are currently stored in a data structure such that $key \in [l, r]$. Add number $v$ to all values, which are paired with those keys. Denotation: $D.add(l, r, v)$.
4. Given a pair of numbers $(l, r)$, consider all keys, which are currently stored in a data structure such that $key \in [l, r]$. Return a maximum of all values, which are paired with those keys. Denotation: $D.get\_max(l, r)$.

We can implement such a data structure so that all operations will have a worst-case time complexity $O(\log n)$. For a detailed discussion about this data structure you can refer to [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/160068/segment-queries-over-a-key-value-store) question.

Now let's describe how to implement the data structure from the current question. First of all, if the data structure currently contains numbers $A = \{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$ then to compute $MRT_w(A)$ it's sufficiently to consider numbers $p_w^A(a_1), \ldots, p_w^A(a_n)$. So let's create a data structure $D$ (from the firs part of the answer) and store there pairs $(a_i, p_w^A(a_i))$. There are 2 main questions that should be answered:

1. How to compute $p_w^A(a)$ when we try to put a new number $a$ into our data structure?
2. How to update values in $D$ during put and remove operations?

Data structure $D$ is implemented on the basis of a binary search tree. So when we put a new number $a$, we can easily compute a number of keys in a data structure, which lie in a segment $[a-w, a+w]$. And this number exactly equals to $p_w^A(a)$. Moreover, the keys which values should be affected by operation $D.put(a, p_w^A(a))$ form a continuous interval and their values lie in a segment $[a-w,a]$. So before we actually call $D.put(a, p_w^A(a))$, we should call $D.add(a-w, a, 1)$.

The same idea works when we remove some key $a$ from our data structure. It affects only consecutive interval of keys, which values lie in $[a-w,a]$ and it decrements their values. So before we call $D.remove(a)$, we should call $D.add(a-w, a, -1)$.

Computation of $MRT_w(A)$ is done by calling $D.get\_max(min, max)$, where $min$ and $max$ are minimal and maximal keys, which are currently stored in a data structure.