# Segment queries over a key-value store

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

We want to implement a data structure, which can store pairs of $(key, value)$ (where $key$ and $value$ are some numbers) and has the following interface:

1. Add $(key, value)$ pair to a data structure (if such key is already in a data structure then ignore this operation).
2. Remove $key$ from a data structure.
3. Given a pair of numbers $(l, r)$ and number $v$, consider all keys, which are currently stored in a data structure such that $key \in [l, r]$. Add number $v$ to all values, which are paired with those keys.
4. Given a pair of numbers $(l, r)$, consider all keys, which are currently stored in a data structure such that $key \in [l, r]$. Return a maximum of all values, which are paired with those keys.

Can we implement all these operations with $O(\log n)$ worst-case time complexity, where $n$ is a number of all keys, which are stored in a data structure, when operation is performed?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Can you build a data structure to support operations 1 and 2 and 4, if you don't have to support operation 3?

Comment: @D.W. My only idea is to modify some standard data structure like segment tree or some self-balancing binary search tree. But for segment trees it's unclear how to support operations 1 and 2. And for BST I have no idea how to support operation 4. Well, for BST I can either implement operation 4 in $O(\log^2 n)$ or in $O(\log n)$ but for rays $[l, +\infty)$ and not for intervals.

Comment: Hm, actually if we can maintain in each node of BST: maximal and minimal keys in its subtree and maximal value in its subtree, then I can implement 1, 2 and 4 in $O(\log n)$. Though I'm not sure whether we can maintain this 3 values during tree rotations.

Comment: Yes, It seems that we can store all 3 values, that I've mentioned in my previous comment. But we should separately store this values for left and for right subtrees of each node. Ok, but I still have no idea how to implement operation 3.

Comment: Great!  You came up with the idea of augmenting a BST, by adding extra information in each internal node to make it easy to compute the max.  Now, can you think of a way to further augment the BST, to make it easy to do operation 3 (in particular, so that operation consists only of updating a few augmented values)?  You might need to adjust your implementation of operation 4 to take into account this extra augmented information.

Comment: @D.W. I think we can add a numerical field "delta" to each internal node. It will mean that the value in this field should be added to all values in a subtree of this node. Then operation 3 is just updating of this field in $O(\log n)$ nodes. But while querying a maximum (operation 4) we now must track an accumulated delta while traversing a tree in order to get a correct value of maximum in particular subtree.

Comment: @D.W. May be you will find it interesting. This data structure gives an $O(n * \log n)$ worst-case time complexity solution for this problem: [link](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/160012/find-a-unit-square-containing-most-of-the-points?noredirect=1&lq=1). Moreover, it's an optimal complexity for this problem in a comparison-based model.

Comment: Sounds like you now have a complete solution - would you be interested to write it up as an answer to your own question?  Or is there some step you cannot see how to handle?

Comment: @D.W. I will try to write an answer for this question myself. Though I'm not sure that I'll have enough time for it in the next few days. Anyway thank you for your help.